# Android battery save

Tags: android, service, save, battery

I have an app which has a service and a main activity. The service runs a count down timer and send an even to the activity which receives the event to paint/refresh the count down timer in the screen. Very simple. Now I am investigating battery usage, which is very very high

I am going to decrease timer tics from 200ms to 800ms and runnable thread of service from 500 to 800. That must save battery I suspect.

But a few questions:

1. My main question: When screen is lock (I have a partial wake lock), does android continues updating the screen? If so I could try not sending refresh information when screen is off (how can I detect screen is locked?). Do you think this can help?
2. Does you know of best practices in programming or app design to save battery? I have been looking for a web about it but have not found anything interesting.
3. Does having database opened waste battery?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

1: You could use the Alarmmanager to perfom the updates. (Have a look here: [android appwidgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html).

> Note: If the device is asleep when it is time for an update (as defined by updatePeriodMillis), then the device will wake up in order to perform the update. If you don't update more than once per hour, this probably won't cause significant problems for the battery life. If, however, you need to update more frequently and/or you do not need to update while the device is asleep, then you can instead perform updates based on an alarm that will not wake the device. To do so, set an alarm with an Intent that your AppWidgetProvider receives, using the AlarmManager. Set the alarm type to either ELAPSED_REALTIME or RTC, which will only deliver the alarm when the device is awake. Then set updatePeriodMillis to zero ("0").

This should be usable for widgets and "normal" acitivities.

2: I don't know an official document. But you should ask yourself following questions: Is it necessary to update that often? If the event is 5 hours away, do you need updates on the GUI every second or just every minute? You could cascade the updates: the closer the event gets, the more frequent the updates become.

3: I think not.

Comment: Alarm manager is not that realtime. He seems to need fast realtime updates, so he shall use surface view and worker thread.

Comment: The question remains, if it has to be really realtime ;)

Comment: realtime updates of the activity ui, but if device locked I only need the service active (partial_wake_lock) to see when countdowntime arrives to cero to run a notification. will be a usefull strategy dont broadcast the time left to the activity?. Can not do it with an alarm and forget the counddowntimer, because if device wake up then the activity ui is not refreshed.

Comment: Your callbacks are onPause() and onResume() - no point updating activity not being shown at the moment.  Just keep countdown time in some convenient location ( static field  of some class )   and look into it from some periodic  task run by your activity

Answer (score 0):

1. (Depending on your code) Your service contunues to run and sends update events consuming CPU cycles and draining power.  Whatever activity you tried to update, it is already paused after screen lock.  There are standard broadcasts for  screen off / screen on  - just receive them in your service and stop working.  Alternatively,  stop your service when activity to be updated receives onPause() callback, and restart it in onResume()  ( no point to refresh activity if it has no focus )
2. see 1 and grok android tutorials. Basic idea: do not do useless stuff.
3. It does not. unless you are querying.